# Explicit imports of Observable operators - I want them back

Tags: rxjs, observable

Developing an angular/cli app, I noticed at some point that failing to explicitly import Observable's operators, as in:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
// import 'rxjs/add/operator/zip';
// import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
```

actually does not prevent the code from compiling. This used to be the case, but I am not sure what caused the change and now commenting out the imports does not stop compilation.

Is this a configuration somewhere or a bad condition of my code? I double-checked - there's not a single greedy import like `import {Observable} from 'rxjs'` that might include all stuff globally in one go.

How can I restore previous behavior where it was necessary to explicitly import individual operators? I sort of liked the requirement as it was an indication that only relevant pieces of package are being imported in the output app.

Comment: if you import the same operator in another module it will serve for the whole project. The recomendation is to import them all in the `app.module.ts` file only.

Comment: Actually, I have commented out **ALL** rxjs operator imports and the app still compiles...

Comment: Maybe they've been imported by an other lib ...

Answer (score 1):

Don't include the whole rxjs - it is huge.

There are two remedies that I use:

- in my IDE (webstorm) there is a configuration that doesn't allow to
  include the whole rxjs.
- all operator' includes are combined in `rxjs-extension.ts` file like that:

  ```
  import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
  import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
  import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
  import 'rxjs/add/observable/empty';

  import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/concat';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/finally';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/pairwise';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/pluck';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/publishLast';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/skip';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMapTo';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeWhile';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/toArray';
  ```

and after that I include this file in app.module.ts and test.ts files.

Comment: Actually, I'm doing my best not to include the whole rxjs: I'm aware of the "blacklist" since WS 2017.1.1, and even before I repeatedly searched for greedy `rxjs` imports. It's just that when I comment the operator imports out, the app still works, which is my concern. Thanks for the suggestion on having the imports gathered in one file though.